# Why do some characters in the string disappear inexplicably after using strip() method in python3?

Tags: python, string, function, strip

The specific code is as follows

```
input = "Please convert 899999999999 using AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkaaaaLlaaa "
output = input.strip('Please convert')

print(output)

899999999999 using AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkaaaaL
```

Can anyone give an explanation?

Comment: It does exactly what the documentation says (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: As of Python 3.9, use [`str.removeprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix).

Answer (score 0):

`strip()` removes all lead and end *characters* taken from the given string, not the literal input provided

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

In other words, `'acelnorstvP '` would yield the same output